# Insertion of Series in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I try to construct a DataFrame using one series, this series becomes column in DataFrame.

```
#name of series become column. All indexes of series become indexes
s= pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, name='joe')
df=pd.DataFrame(s)
print(df)
     joe
a     1
b     2
c     3
```

But when a list of series is provided, all series become rows in DataFrame.

```
# indexes become columns. series name become row name
s1= pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, name='joe')
s2=pd.Series({'a':4,'b':5,'c':6}, name='john')
slist=[s1,s2]
df=pd.DataFrame(slist)
print(df)
     a    b   c
joe  1    2   3
john 4    5   6
```

Why is this difference in handling? Why can't a series always become row in DataFrame, irrespective of whether a list is provided or a single Series. I am sure Pandas developers didn't just do it on a whim.

After the creation of a DataFrame, if I try to append a single
Series, then it gets appended as row.

```
import pandas as pd
s1= pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, name='s1')
s2=pd.Series({'a':4,'b':5,'c':6}, name='s2')
slist=[s1,s2]
df=pd.DataFrame(slist)
s=pd.Series({'b':1}, name='s3')
df=df.append(s)
print(df)

     a    b    c
s1  1.0  2.0  3.0
s2  4.0  5.0  6.0
s3  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Please don't post images of the text. Post as text itself.

Comment: Removed images.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference, because in second sample use list of Series, so if need row in first is necessary one lement list `[s]`:

```
s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2}, name='joe')
#list of Series
df = pd.DataFrame([s])
print (df)
     a  b
joe  1  2
```

---

```
s1 = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2}, name='joe')
s2 = pd.Series({'a':4,'b':5}, name='john')
#list of Series
df = pd.DataFrame([s1,s2])
print (df)
      a  b
joe   1  2
john  4  5
```

In my opinion one `Series`s is parsed to column, because in `DataFrame` each column is `Series` with some `dtype`.

[DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe):

> DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dict of Series objects.

Comment: My question is basically, why Pandas developers make this behaviour different? Why can't a series always become row in DataFrame, irrespective of whether a list is provided or a single Series.

Comment: @victini - Hmmm, I dont understand why do you think different structures have to return same outputs? Because if use list of Series it working same way, like my answer, but if use different it is expected different outputs. But I am not pandas developer, so added only my idea.

Comment: When we try to insert a single series using append function into a DataFrame, then also it gets appended as row. Then why just in one case, it becomes column?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: @victini - It is expected with function [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is added new row - docs say `Append rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a new object.`